# Mongoose Schema with SubDocument fields that are required

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Following Joe Eames tutorial, ***"Building AngularJS and Node.js Apps with the MEAN Stack"*** at [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Description/building-angularjs-nodejs-apps-mean), he demonstrates an example of a Mongoose Schema with document fields that are required, as follows:

```
var courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type:String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  featured: {type:Boolean, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  published: {type:Date, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
  tags: [String]
   });
```

I have created my own schema, with a sub-document that works:

```
  ......
  skin : {styleNum : String, headerLogo: String},
  ......
```

However, I want the fields to be required and the subdocument is not an array (in Entity Framework it would be akin to an association, not a collection), so this is wrong:

```
  ......
  skin : [
          {styleNum : String, required:'{PATH} is required!'},
          {headerLogo: String, required:'{PATH} is required!'}
         ]
  ......
```

What would be the correct syntax for creating an 'Entity Framework"-like association in a Mongoose Schema where both fields are required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Nevermind, figured where my error was:**

```
 skin : {
     styleNum: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'},
     headerLogo: {type: String, required: '{PATH} is required!'}
 },
```